# Firebase , Angular 4 Root Module & Feature Module - "No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp()."

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

In my app, I have a root module (app.module.ts) and a feature module (contact.module.ts). I use AngularFireModule, as setup (below) in the root module, and for some reason, I'm getting this error: "error_handler.js:47 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp()." I'm wondering why.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule, AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { environment} from '../environments/environment';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ContactModule} from "./customer/customer.module";
import { AuthenticationService } from "./authentication/authentication.service";

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
   AppComponent
 ],
 imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   ReactiveFormsModule,
   HttpModule,
   AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
   AngularFireDatabaseModule,
   AngularFireAuthModule,
   ContactModule
 ],
 providers: [AuthenticationService],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
 production: false,
 firebase = {
   apiKey: "",
   authDomain: "",
   databaseURL: "",
   projectId: "",
   storageBucket: "",
   messagingSenderId: ""
 }
}
```

**contact.ts (v1)**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
  //...
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {
  //...
  constructor(private _router: Router) {
    // Get a reference to the storage service
    const storageSvc = firebase.storage();

    // Create a storage reference from our storage service
    const storageRef = storageSvc.ref();

    const picStorageRef = storageRef.child('contacts/pic1.jpg');

    picStorageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => this.picURL = url);
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Again, for some reason, I'm getting this error: "error_handler.js:47 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp()."

I tried to move the firebase config object from the **environment.ts** file to the app.module.ts file, but it did not resolve the error. It only works when I import firebase in the contact.ts file as such:

**contact.ts (v2)**

```
//...
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

//...
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {
 //...
 constructor(//...) {
   firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);
   // Get a reference to the storage service
    const storageSvc = firebase.storage();

    // Create a storage reference from our storage service
    const storageRef = storageSvc.ref();

    const picStorageRef = storageRef.child('contacts/pic1.jpg');

    picStorageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => this.picURL = url);
 }
}
```

This may has something to do with the implementation of the feature module **contact.module.ts**. And just so you know, I also tried to move the firebase config to the **contact.module.ts** bu the error remains. So I would like to know how to set a firebase configuration application wide, to get it running, instead of having to initialize firebase from the contact.ts file.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I see you initialized AngularFire, but you did not initialize Firebase.

Comment: @StevenScott thanks for your prompt answer. In my understanding, AngularFire does the initialization in the imports of the app.module as such:

`AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)`
 
I'm trying to figure this out. Would you please tell me how to initialize firebase in this case?!

Comment: I  think you need to basically do the same thing, just with the Firebase reference, not your AngularFire object.

Comment: @StevenScott Well, I tried that but still getting another error.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using Firebase storage.  I get the data from my AngularFire instance without a problem, and do not need to initialize Firebase directly.

Comment: Do you think you can show me some codes so I can see how you manage that?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Take a look at this plunker -> https://plnkr.co/edit/YfaYs0

Comment: I looked at your plunker. I think the issue with mine comes probably from the fact that I'm using a feature module (contact.module.ts), besides the root module (app.module.ts). In the doc [basic links](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule), they say "What AppModule imports is irrelevant to ContactModule and vice versa". So I'm wondering if this also applies to the `AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)` import.

Comment: I used it in the app.module.ts as I am using it in many pages, so I am only looking to initialize it once, not on each page.

Comment: This could explain why I have to initialize firebase using the firebase sdk in the component, like I did (`firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase)`) in the `contact.ts`. And it's working. Which means that I will have to do the same initialization on every component where firebase is needed?!.

Comment: Not sure as I do not use it, but if it is working as you indicate, then it does appear that you might have to add it to every module.

Comment: OK! Unless any other comment suggests otherwise, I will do as you suggest.
Thanks a lot